# Is XPath 3.1 100% upwardly compatible with XPath 2.0?

Tags: xpath, saxon, xpath-2.0

We are using Saxon, calling it from Java, to perform queries. When we upgrade to XPath 3.1, will it handle all queries written for XPath 2.0 the same as before? Or are there changes in what is returned for some queries?

I'm asking because if it's 100% upwardly compatible, we just change our existing XPath 2.0 code to use XPath 3.1. But if it's different, then we need to add XPath 3.1 as a new datasource type.

We do have XPath 1.0 as a distinct datasource because there are differences between what XPath 1.0 and 2.0 return for some queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assure this premise by following this chain:

[XPath-3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-backwards-compatibility) is backwards compatible to XPath-2.0

> This appendix provides a summary of the areas of incompatibility between XPath 3.0 and [XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0]. In each of these cases, **an XPath 3.0 processor is compatible with an XPath 2.0 processor.**

[XPath-3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-backwards-compatibility) is backwards compatible to XPath-3.0.

> This Recommendation specifies **XPath version 3.1, a fully compatible extension of XPath version 3.0.**

Answer (score 1):

XPath 3.1 allows new expressions for arrays, maps and functions so if you have a test suite checking for some syntax errors in XPath 2 expressions you might find they could be allowed in XPath 3.1 and don't give an error.

The main error I remember to be converted into legal syntax  is `foo/[bar]` which constructs an array in XPath 3.1 in the last step.

Comment: I'm not worried about previously bad queries now working, just that 2.0 valid ones act the same in 3.1. Looks like they do which is great news.